# How to SSH VirtualBox from an external network?

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, putty, centos-7

I have a static IP, which is provided by the Vodafone home fibre broadband and I am trying to connect my VM, but it is refusing to connect. I am using VirtualBox 6.1.2 and CentOS 7. I have been attempting to use NAT, NAT Networking and Bridge adapter, but no good luck. I am new to virtual networking. I am sure if I am missing something.

There are tons of information online for within network but not any to SSH Oracle VM from an external network? Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Shah, and welcome! Is your static IP from Vodafone assigned to your whole home network, or is it a second IP assigned to just the CentOS box? Also, is the VM in question the only VM on the machine that needs to be accessed via SSH either locally or remotely, or are there multiple VMs? Finally, do you need SSH access to the CentOS host machine at all?

Comment: Even if you have a static IP this does not necessarily mean that your computer has this IP. Usually this means that the used cable modem/router has this IP and provides private addresses fro your network.

Comment: @Robert. Thanks for coming back to me. My port was not enabled by the Vodafone. When I requested them for IP whitelisting the port is forwarding is working for the webserver but I am not sure how can I SSH my VM from the external network?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information missing from your question, so we'll go for a basic fault-seeking exercise.

There are two places where you need to look at the network:

- the VirtualBox environment
- the broadband access

First have a look at the VirtualBox environment. The easiest would be to put it in bridged mode. If you have another system on your network between the VirtualBox-host and the broadband provider, you should be able to check if your CentOS is accessible from outside your VirtualBox-host.

If it is not accessible, try the other way around: can you access the "other" system from your CentOS? A ping should be sufficient. Is the CentOS in the same subnet as the 'outside' network? Make sure that the host and the CenOS have a different IP address. Things like that.

Once your able to access the CentOS from your local 'outside' network, look at the broadband access. What type is it? If it is NAT (as often is the case in home access stuff) is port forwarding configured correctly (i.e. to the CentOS, not to the VirtualBox host)?

You should now have sufficient pointers to work on.

Comment: @Lim, thanks for your help. I have the Vodafone router which has a public IP. I have two pc connected via the router with different static IP and the VirtualBoxes also have their own static IP and a hostname. As my IP was not whitelisted from Vodafone I was having a problem with port forwarding. I have done the port forwarding for one of the pc and still, I can not SSh to it from an external network. I can SSH and PING both PC internally. Could you please let me know how can I SSH my static IP from an external network?